# jQuery Select all TextBoxes within one element but not another

Tags: jquery-selectors

This one shouldn't be too hard...

I have a DIV named X, which contains child DIV's A, B, and C (no those aren't the real names).  The following jQuery properly selects all textboxes from within DIV X and its children:

```
var theFields = $("input:text", $("div[id$='X']"));
```

However, DIV C is an exception and should be skipped.  How do I select all textboxes within DIV X and its children, but skip those in child DIV C?  I've used the :NOT operator before, but I'm not sure how to use it here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div#X input:not(div#C > input)')
```

Comment: Not sure.  I simplified my query for the question, and now that I have the simple answer, I'm trying to expand that to a more complicated query.  If I specifically want inputs of type text & checkbox, why doesn't this work?:  $("div#X input:text, input:checkbox:not(div#C > input:text, input:checkbox)")   -Also, why is the ">" only in the :not() part of the query?